# SSRS - Batch printing grouping Issue? Report seems to be randomly messing up PO Number and page numbering

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-grouping, purchase-order

I'm using MS Report Builder v15.0.19210.0.

I have an SSRS report that is driving me crazy.  If it is used to print a PO individually, all is well.  The issue starts when the report style is used to print a batch.  When used to print a batch, some of the POs are printing with the following fields sometimes incorrect:
-PO Numbers (sometimes jump to next PO # on pages after first page of PO)
-Order Date (sometimes blank on pages after first page of PO)

The last batch was 45 pages and included 29 Purchase Orders.  All look good until page 14, where on page 2 of the PO, the PO number changes.  (It's supposed to be 23661 but it shows 23662.)  Then after that, PO numbers are incorrect on many pages (after the first page) on each PO.

[PO Number on first page of PO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wcil.png)
[PO Number on second page of PO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9KO4.png)

I have been working on this for a week, but I'm not getting there.  It must be something with the grouping, but I can't find it and I'm afraid I'm making it worse.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  In the meantime, my Purchasing Dept is having to print these individually, which is not ideal.

I would really appreciate any help.  If I haven't given enough relevant info, please let me know what I'm missing.  I'm not sure what to post, and I don't see a way to attach the .rdl.

Thank you,
Erin

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will probably need to include the following. `1.` a screenshot of your report design including the row groups if applicable `2.`  The expressions used in your row groups `3.` A sample of your dataset when more than 1 PO is selected. `4.` describe how users select more than 1 PO (assume this is from a drop down parameter but need to be sure). If you start there then I'm sure somebody will be able to help or ask more relevant questions. Please edit you question to include the above. For sample data just replace sensitive data with "Company A" "Address A" etc.

Comment: Can we attach to posts?

Comment: You can't attach files, you will have to insert screen shots and for the dataset sample, try to add that as text if possible, use the code format button at the top of the text editor to make sure it's clear. You will have to edit your original question, don't try to add extra content in the comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try making a copy of the report with just a table of the data from the dataset. Is there one line per PO number? And does each one have the correct order number? This will help determine if the issue is in the data or the report design. If the data is correct, screenshots of the report design and group properties would help identify the actual issue.